# C++ casting a base pointer to an interface pointer

Tags: c++, casting, rtti

Here is some pseudo code of my setup:

```
class IMyClass { ... }; // pure virtual class
class CMyBaseClass { .... };
class CMyClass : public CMyBaseClass, public IMyClass { ... }
```

Then I have collection of CMyBaseClass*. I have custom RTTI that allows me to find out if a class implements given interface. So I can find which of the objects have IMyClass implementation. My problem is that I can't cast it to that interface. I don't want to use standard RTTI and dynamic cast.

I'm thinking in my custom RTTI to store some pointer diffs for casting between pair of classes, but I haven't figure out implementation that makes me happy.

Any other solutions?

Comment: Don't think there are any other solutions, 'cause it's purely RTTI's responsibility to know how to cast, because you have to cast first to proper `CMyClass*` (or another descendant) and then "back" to the actual interface.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom RTTI"?  Why don't you want to use "standard RTTI" to solve this?  The need to perform dynamic casting often implies a design problem; are you sure you can't think of a more elegant (i.e. polymorphic) architecture?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the language RTTI? Since you are using interfaces, that means that you already have virtual functions, so you are not really avoid the standard RTTI... If you explain what parts of RTTI you do not want and why, you might get some solutions.

Comment: Hmmm... I really need custom RTTI. By using my own implementation I have automatic serialization/deserialization, binding with scripting languages, some debugging tools, etc. I just don't feel like I should use the language RTTI if I already have my own that can give me all the information for the hierarchy except figuring out the vtables. I can add support for this cast as well but I'm not crazy about my solution so I was hopping that I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you insist in not using the language RTTI, you can use just like the old COM: make all your classes or interfaces derive from the following interface:

```
class IMyCast  // similar to IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual void *CastTo(interfaceId_t id) = 0; //Similar to IUnknown::QueryInterface
};
```

Now in your CMyClass:

```
class CMyClass : public CMyBaseClass, public IMyClass
{
    //...
    void *CastTo(interfaceId_t id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case IMyClass_id: //or whatever
                return static_cast<IMyClass*>(this);
            //...other cases
            default:
                throw std::bad_cast(); //or return NULL
        }
    }
};
```

Then in the user code:

```
CMyBaseClass *obj;
IMyClass *my = static_cast<IMyClass*>(obj->CastTo(IMyClass_id));
```

Comment: How does `static_cast` do its magic inside the compiler? Sorry, I know not directly related to the question, but came here looking for an answer to this because I would like to understand QueryInterface() better. Thank you.

Comment: @Sabuncu: Well, for `static_cast<>` both the source and destination types are known at compile time, so the conversion is just a change of type and a possible fixed offset. The compiler just keeps a table for every type with the offsets of every base type.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you'll need to augment your custom RTTI; at least this is what I did in pretty much the same situation. Instead of using pointer diffs, my solution instantiates a "caster" function template for the necessary (Class, Interface) pairs. It's something like this:

- All interfaces have a unique int id. For this a MyInterface needs to be derived from InterfaceBase. The id is assigned automatically on the first MyInterface::GetId() call.
- The implementor of MyClass (that implements MyInterface) needs to add an IMPLEMENTS(MyClass, MyInterface) macro in a .cpp file.
- The macro instantiates a `void* GetInterface<C, I>(void*)` function, and then registers a pointer to this function in an interfaceId -> GetInterface-function map (that belongs to class C). This function casts its argument into C*, then the C* into I*, and finally back to void*. (The hacking with void*'s is necessary so that all these functions have the same signature, thus they can be stored in a map.)
- To get an interface, the user needs to call a myObject->GetInterface() function, implemented in CMyBaseClass. It finds the map that belongs to the dynamic class of the `this` object, looks up the appropriate caster function based on I::GetId(), and calls it passing `this`.